# Which is the best way to fetch data for multiple information? (Redux,Mongodb)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I am trying to display a bunch of statistical information in a React page. I am using MongoDb, Express.js, React and Redux. Considering that I have to display a bunch of statistical information, I can do those in two ways. The first way is by making queries to the database for each one of the statistical information that I need and store them on Redux state, or I can make few queries and from there I can derive other statistical information. Which is the best way to do that?

If I follow the first way, I end up with a complex Redux state and not reusing some of the information provided by other queries. If I follow the second way I end up deriving complex information in the client side.

Which is the preferred way?

Comment: try graphql (apollo) - fetch only what you want, data in (querable) normalized cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show us some examples related to your data. What information are you going to show? How related those pieces of information between them? How complex those queries? How much time does it take to show a piece of information to a user? How fast your API results? Do you want to show those pieces of information asynchronous or sync?

To define your structure you need to make sure about your user story. So it depends on  Currently, users are expecting to see information separately (async) with some content loader and do some actions in the same way. So it is good to divide your components into small pieces. So each big component (organism) makes API calls and shows information to a user with small components.

When it comes to state management if pieces of information are dependent on each other it is good to use Redux and define reducers actions etc. so you can keep track of your state in a bigger scope. If those pieces of information only need and auth key or user data, you can use [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) in your organisms to make your API calls that get auth information from [ContextProviders](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

If you are capable of creating microservices (or if you have them), I would recommend you to try to react hooks. If you have different API's which shows different info use redux.